# Permission denied during deletion of folder in UBUNTU

Tags: permissions, chown

I am the owner of the destined folder and also in group.
I used chown to take all permissions and enabled creat and delete file option. But even then when i tried to delete it; permission denied pops on.

commands used by me:

```
 sudo chown -R owner_name:group_name directory_name
 or
 sudo chown owner_name:group_name directory_name
```

The first one for recursion for subfolders and files
and the second one for destined one.

I am actually tryna delete the folder made by Intellij that is now I am trying to uninstall.

Comment: You will probably have to use `sudo` to delete the folder as the parent folder of the folder you are trying to delete is probably not owned by you.  Don't change the ownership or permissions of the parent folder as you might mess up applications residing in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there might be  a subfolder with other users ownership say ROOT ownership so if you try to delete parent folder with in your ownership shows permission denied. So if you don't care about this folder and want to delete it anyway, then become root by issuing `sudo su` and then execute next remove dir command by issuing `rm -rf <directory-name>`. Be careful that you are running with rm command with root privileges, so double check the folders and contents prior deleting.

Comment: well; i didn't focus on your warnings that time and caught into some terrible things like breaking sudo and sudoers. I know this was terrible one; but now i am ok.  :p